# Retractable UITabBarController / UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm looking to implement something similar to the Mashable app article view. When clicked through to read an article and begin to scroll down the Navigation controller slides up off screen and the Tab bar controller slides down.

I'm open to other suggestions but the goal here is to not see the tab bar controller while in the article view while keeping tab bar controller as my root controller.

I'm still learning Objective-C so my skill set is somewhat limited so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Justing noticed the New York Times app does this as well so I'm guessing it is practical, Just an observation, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-[UINavigationController setToolbarHidden:animated:]
```

will do what you want for the navigation controller.  I don't know how to accomplish the same thing with a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question but forgot to post. The way to do so is with

> **viewcontroller**.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;